# Is there an "add_months" function in xpath?

Tags: commcare

I know I can write something like: new_date = if(month = 12, date(year+1, 1, day), date(year, month+1,day)

But hoping there is some function that can do that for me instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes write it in a rearranged format where I calculate the year, then the month, then the day and then concatenate.  Depending on how the exact equations fall out (and because "year", "month", "day" are actually long expressions), it sometimes looks cleaner.

new_date = concat(year + if(month = 12, 1, 0), if(month = 12, 1, month), day)

This doesn't really solve the problem that there is no clean way to add months in our calendar (which are different numbers of days).  Perhaps we should all switch to the Ethiopian calendar where every month has 30 days.  Turns out this kind of calculation is one thing that is actually much easier in that system!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a concept of adding [timedeltas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) in CommCare. A close way to approximate is by converting the date to an integer and adding the number of days you'd like.

```
>>> int(date('1970-1-1'))
>>> 0
>>> int(date('1970-1-3'))
>>> 2
```

This demonstrates how you can convert a date to an integer. Now you can add a month by adding 30

```
>>> date(int(date('1970-1-1')) + 30)
>>> 1970-01-31
```

Of course the major caveat with this is that it adds 30 days not one month.

Comment: "Of course the major caveat with this is that it adds 30 days not one month"   .... yeah, that's my main barrier I'm trying to solve.